# What is the "Open standard" principle?

Tags: open-source

**What are the open standard principles ?**
I googled it but I am getting different answer from different website cant decide what to write

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty confusing concept because it is NOT the same as open source.
Open source means you can get the CODE and use it in whatever way you need (make your own changes etc).

Open standard means you can get the PROGRAM / TECHNOLOGY for free. To put it very roughly, open standard is that you can get a complied ".exe" executable (but no source code), and install the software at no cost, and open source means you can have the code, make your own changes, and then make your own ".exe" if you want.

HTML and XML are open standard technologies.